# Java "invalid stream header" error

Tags: java, file, sockets

I'm having issues sending a file from one person to another in my program, I get a "invalid stream header" error.  Here is the code for sending and receiving the file, respectively:

```
private void sendFile(Socket socket, File file) throws IOException
{
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] buffer;
    FileInputStream input;
    OutputStream output;
    buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    input = new FileInputStream(file);
    output = socket.getOutputStream();
    bytesRead = input.read(buffer);

    while(bytesRead > 0)
    {
        output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
        bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();
}



private void receiveFile(Socket socket, File file) throws IOException
{
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] buffer;
    InputStream input;
    FileOutputStream output;
    buffer = new byte[(int)file.length()];
    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    input = socket.getInputStream();
    bytesRead = input.read(buffer);

    while(bytesRead > 0)
    {
        output.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
        bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
    }

    input.close();
    output.close();
}
```

I've already read up on Stack and everything I've tried hasn't fixed it.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Exact error is:

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 3C736372
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at Message.readMessageFrom(Message.java:32)
    at Server$Handler.run(Server.java:220)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Please show the *exact* exception, including the stack trace.

Comment: Something is omitted here. Your stack trace shows you entering a `Message` class with a `readMessageFrom` method but that method is not in your code. So the code that you display is not involved (though it has the curious feature of using the destination file's current size to allocate the buffer, which may not work).

Comment: The Message class is working as it should - and I just did notice that byte allocation error and fixed it.

Comment: No, it's clearly not - it's throwing an exception. But the code you've posted isn't involved *anywhere* in the stack trace, so there must be something going on here. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and give more context. Until you explain more, there's no way we can help you.